# Error while loading shared libraries: libnuma.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, linux, centos7

## Summarize in short:

Installing mysql on centos7(without yum), I already installed numactl, but still get the error:

```
Installing MySQL system tables.../usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: 
error while loading shared libraries: libnuma.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

## Promblem detail:

I'm installing mysql on linux centos7(without yum), when initializing scripts/mysql_install_db , error info coming:

```
Installing MySQL system tables.../usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: 
error while loading shared libraries: libnuma.so.1: cannot open shared object file: 
No such file or directory ;
```

I searched some suggestion that numactl needed. But i already installed numactl:

```
[root@foo scripts]# sudo yum install numactl -y
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Package numactl-2.0.9-7.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

when running scripts/mysql_install_db again, error info still coming.
Any sugetstions?

Comment: What is the output of `ldd /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld` and `find /usr/lib -name 'libnuma.so*'`?

Comment: Assuming an Autotools project... You should state how you configured both MySQL and libnuma.

Comment: Hi @Danila Kiver `ldd /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld` --> No such file or directory and `find /usr/lib -name 'libnuma.so*'`--> blank output

Comment: Hi @jww I think i didn't config libnuma. For mysql like this: `
basedir = /usr/local/mysql
datadir = /usr/local/mysql/data
port = 3306
# server_id = .....
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
character-set-server = utf8
skip-name-resolve
log-err = /usr/local/mysql/data/error.log
pid-file = /usr/local/mysql/data/mysql.pid

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
`

Comment: `libnuma.so.1` is provided by the package `numactl-libs` .... : `# yum provides */libnuma.so.1`

Comment: Thanks @KnudLarsen, tyied this , `[root@foo mysql]# yum provides */libnuma.so.1
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
numactl-libs-2.0.9-7.el7.i686 : libnuma libraries
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/libnuma.so.1



numactl-libs-2.0.9-7.el7.x86_64 : libnuma libraries
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libnuma.so.1



numactl-libs-2.0.9-7.el7.x86_64 : libnuma libraries
Repo        : @ anaconda
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libnuma.so.1
`   still coming same error info;

Comment: `# yum install numactl-libs.i686 numactl-libs.x86_64`

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thanks , this sovled my issue.

Comment: this command `sudo yum install numactl -y` work for me

Answer (score 15):

I solved this problem:

```
sudo apt-get install libnuma-dev
```

Comment: `yum install numactl` for RedHat-based Linux Distributions.

Comment: pacman -S numactl